# How to get remaining route/coordinates from current navigation route

Tags: android, ios, here-api

Is there a way to get the remaining route or coordinates from the current navigation route while driving? I am using HERE SDK for Android (Premium Edition) 3.15. Example: If the whole route is 100% and I've driven 20%, I would like to get the remaining 80% of the route/coordinates.

PS: If I can get the next waypoint that I need to pass through would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

VenueNavigationManager and FTCRNavigationManager(in beta) provides methods that can get the distance travelled, also the method that returns the remaining time and distance. Including the API references for the premium Android Edition :
https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/3.16/api_reference_java/index.html?com%2Fhere%2Fandroid%2Fmpa%2Fvenues3d%2FVenueNavigationManager.html

&
https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/3.16/api_reference_java/index.html?com%2Fhere%2Fandroid%2Fmpa%2Fftcr%2FFTCRNavigationManager.html